# Azure AD UPN swap between two accounts

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Recently I re-created a personal account for a user in a fully cloud M365 tenant.
They used to be a guest, but in order to fully manage the account, we settled for creating a proper, new one.

Problem? UPN. Guest account was set to "member" and already had a UPN set to "first_name.last_name@domain". I unassigned it from the guest 48h ago thinking I can then use it for the new account. Admin Center returns a 500 error, Azure AD tells me to try again later. So I tried to use PowerShell, and here's where it gets confusing to me:

`Set-MsolUserPrincipalName` returns:

> Unable to change the user name because the name you chose uses a user
> principal name that already exists.

`Get-MsolUser` for the same UPN returns:

> User Not Found.

Where could this UPN still exist?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error like below:***

```
Set-MsolUserPrincipalName -UserPrincipalName "ruk@xxx.onmicrosoft.com" -NewUserPrincipalName "rukmini3394@xxx.onmicrosoft.com"
```

[image]

The error usually occurs if the UPN still exists when you are trying to `Set-MsolUserPrincipalName`.

***To resolve the error, try the below:***

Fetch the deleted users and check:

```
Connect-MsolService
Get-MsolUser -ReturnDeletedUsers
```

[image]

Delete the user like below:

```
Remove-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName "rukmini@xxx.onmicrosoft.com"
```

[image]

Try the below command to **delete the user permanently**:

```
Remove-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName "rukmini#@xxx.onmicrosoft.com" -RemoveFromRecycleBin
```

[image]

After performing the above, **I am able to set the deleted user UPN to another user** like below:

```
Set-MsolUserPrincipalName -UserPrincipalName "ruk@xxx.onmicrosoft.com" -NewUserPrincipalName "rukmini3394@xxx.onmicrosoft.com"
```

[image]

[image]

If still issue persists, wait for some more time as there might be replication delay.

**Otherwise**, refer the below MsDoc:

[Clean up unmanaged Azure AD accounts - Azure Active Directory - Microsoft Entra](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/clean-up-unmanaged-azure-ad-accounts#reset-redemption-using-msidentitytools-powershell-module)

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your reply.
This indeed is the way to solve it if we take deleting the user A as an option. Yes. But I still wonder, when trying to take a UPN from user A and assign it to user B, where is this UPN stored? It's not assigned, it's not possible to look it up and it's not possible to assign it to any other user.

Comment: If still the persists, contact Azure Support to resolve the issue.